# Using Aggregation Framework to restructure data from a given entry

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm a relatively newbie developer diving into MongoDB and Mongoose.

I have a quite specific problem, and I wasn't sure how to phrase the question in order for it to make sense.

Basically, I have "appointments" entries which look like this:

```
{
    "_id": "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0c",
    "customer_id": "123",
    "date": "2021-04-30T18:00:00.000Z",
    "requested_services": [
      {
        "_id": "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0d",
        "service_ref_id": "60489ec10acf063c366be0c4",
        "start_time": "2021-04-10T10:00:00.000Z",
        "duration": 1,
        "price": 170,
        "notes": "Mireasa"
      },
      {
        "_id": "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0e",
        "service_ref_id": "60489ec10acf063c366be0c4",
        "start_time": "2021-04-10T10:00:00.000Z",
        "duration": 1,
        "price": 170,
        "notes": "Nasa"
      }
    ],
    "is_archived": false
  }
```

What I wanna do is aggregate each "appointment" and return an array which contains a document for each entry in "requested_services",  like the following:

```
{
“appointment_id”: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"customer_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"_id": "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0d",
"service_ref_id": "60489ec10acf063c366be0c4",
"start_time": "2021-04-10T10:00:00.000Z",
"duration": 1,
"price": 170,
"notes": “Mireasa"
}
```

So basically for each requested service in every appointment, I want to list out the appointment ID, the customer ID and then the requested service data.

I tried figuring this out with grouping and projecting, but I really cannot wrap my head around it.

Could someone point me into the right direction? The documentation doesn't really help me since I'm not even sure what to look for.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) `requested_services` array and then reshape it using `$project` operator. So `$unwind` operator dissects the `requested_services` array and each item in `requested_services` will receive its parent's data.

Try this:

```js
db.appointments.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$requested_services"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            appointment_id: "$_id",
            customer_id: "$customer_id",
            _id: "$requested_services._id",
            service_ref_id: "$requested_services.service_ref_id",
            start_time: "$requested_services.start_time",
            duration: "$requested_services.duration",
            price: "$requested_services.price",
            notes: "$requested_services.notes"
        }
    }
]);
```

Output

```js
/* 1 */
{
    "appointment_id" : "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0c",
    "customer_id" : "123",
    "_id" : "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0d",
    "service_ref_id" : "60489ec10acf063c366be0c4",
    "start_time" : "2021-04-10T10:00:00.000Z",
    "duration" : 1,
    "price" : 170,
    "notes" : "Mireasa"
},

/* 2 */
{
    "appointment_id" : "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0c",
    "customer_id" : "123",
    "_id" : "6064bb7a9724c40e19113a0e",
    "service_ref_id" : "60489ec10acf063c366be0c4",
    "start_time" : "2021-04-10T10:00:00.000Z",
    "duration" : 1,
    "price" : 170,
    "notes" : "Nasa"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So based on Dheemanth Bhat answer that pointed me to look deeper into the unwind stage, I finally solved my problem. The way my schemas are designed required an additional unwind:

```
router.route('/:id/appointments/read/all/:year/:month').get(verify, async (req, res) => {

    User.aggregate()

    // Separate each appointment into its own document
    .unwind('appointments')

    // Get all the appointments from the current user that match the selected date
    .match({
        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id),
        'appointments.date': {
            $gte: new Date(parseInt(req.params.year), parseInt(req.params.month) - 1, 1),
            $lte: new Date(parseInt(req.params.year), parseInt(req.params.month) - 1, 31)
        }
    })

    // Separate each requested service of each appointment into its own document
    .unwind('appointments.requested_services')

    // Format the result of each requested service
    .project({
        appointment_id: '$appointments._id',
        _id: '$appointments.requested_services._id',
        service_ref_id: '$appointments.requested_services.service_ref_id',
        start_time: '$appointments.requested_services.start_time',
        duration: '$appointments.requested_services.duration',
        notes: '$appointments.requested_services.notes'
    })

    .sort({start_time: 1})

    // Send the filtered appointments array
    .exec((error, result) => {
        if (error) return res.status(400).send('Something went wrong: ' + error);
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```

Since this is a very specific case, I've left my code here in case someone has a similar problem.